# How to jq to copy array inside the dictionary?

Tags: json, linux, jq

I have the following json

```
   [ 
       { 
          "name":"bucket1"
       },
       { 
          "name":"bucket1"
       }
    ]
```

I want to convert it to

```
{ 
   "buckets":[ 
      { 
         "name":"bucket1"
      },
      { 
         "name":"bucket1"
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I do this with jq?

Comment: can you elaborate more about the issue you are having? add a code snippet to give more context on the problem.

Comment: [`{ buckets : . }`](https://jqplay.org/s/u9MRRWEvv3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution is the following:**

```
{"buckets":.}
```

**In the Command line:**

```
jq '{"buckets":.}'
```

See:https://jqplay.org/s/MJ-GoLOBX2

---

There is more documentation available at:

https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/json-and-jq#the-dot-

Also see the hints below [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/MJ-GoLOBX2) at the bottom.